# Clarification on L'Hopital's rule proof for $x \to a$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-explanation

For this variation of L'Hopital's rule:

Let $f, g$ be differentiable in neighborhood of $a$.
Given that:

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=0$$
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L, L \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$g'(x) \neq 0$$
So $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$

In the proof I've seen, we redefine $f, g$ so $f(a)=g(a)=0$, then we prove that for every $x_n \to a^+$ there is $c_{x_n} \to a^+$ such that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(x_n)}{g(x_n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f'(c_{x_n})}{g'(c_{x_n})}$$

And that is due to the fact that $\frac{f(x_n)}{g(x_n)}=\frac{f'(c_{x_n})}{g'(c_{x_n})}$

And then the same for $x_n \to a^-$. Here is my question:

If the limit of $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ doesn't exist, why isn't it implies that the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ doesn't exist? After all, the two expressions are proven to be equal without taking in consideration that the limit exists.

I hope that I made myself clear. I'm not writing the entire proof because I don't think it is important for the question itself.

Thank you

Comment: Indeed, extending $f$ and $g$ to $a$ in the obvious way allows you to apply the (generalized) mean value theorem whence it follows that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(\xi_x)}{g'(\xi_x)}$.

Comment: Indeed, there is no guarantee that the term $f'(a)/g'(a)$ would exist. It's rather the contrary: if it does, then the rule of L'Hopital tells what the asked for limit would be. However, you might consider to apply L'Hospital again and look for the second derivatives, etc.

Comment: @OliverDíaz It is the same question, but it doesn't fully answer it. I still wonder how two expressions can be equal but one doesn't have a limit, and the other does.